# What to do with multiple observables of varying types?

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I saw some code today that made me cringe, but I wasn't sure how to fix it.

Essentially the code was using `.zip` on multiple calls to semi-chain them together and then act on the result:

```
Observable.zip(service.getObservable1(), service.getObservable2(), service.getObservable3(), new Func3<Type1, Type2, Type3>(){
     public Object call(Type1 type1, Type2 type2, Type3 type3){
          // set a bunch of globals
          mGlobalState.setType1(type1);
          mGlobalState.setType2(type2);
          mGlobalSession.setType3(type3);
          return null;
     }
}).subscribe(mObserver);
```

So many things seem wrong; setting global state in the .zip call, returning null, and not actually using the .zip for its intended purpose. Also, the observer's `onNext` doesn't use the result, but depends on the side effects of setting the global state in .zip.

The motivation is that all of these observables only emit once (they are API calls) and we want to wait for them all to complete before caching the values returned, and then progressing to the next logical screen in the application.

I am not sure what to do with this call. We cannot use lambda's on our version of Java and I haven't found a clean solution that isn't five times as long.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that an elegant solution is create an object to group all received data and emit then as the result of your `zip` function.

```
@Test
public void testSample() {
    Observable<String> a = Observable.just("a");
    Observable<Integer> b = Observable.just(1);
    Observable<Boolean> c = Observable.just(true);

    Observable.zip(a, b, c, Result::new).subscribe(result -> {
        // save data into your globals
    });
}

public class Result {
    private final String a;
    private final int b;
    private final boolean c;

    public Result(String a, int b, boolean c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public boolean isC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many Android developers use Retrolambda to do the backporting of lambdas at build time and have some of the benefits of Java 8 while remaining compatible.

You can set your global variables from the function if you know there will be only a single call that does it, but this structure also implies you have to block somewhere until the zip does its job before the code can move onto the next logical screen.